# Translations on Facebook event feed

Tags: facebook, events, translation

I'm reading the events of a band on Facebook via the PHP SDK. I get all the event- and venue-data, but some city names are not translated into German (e.g. Munich has to be München). I tried to set the locale parameter (de, de_DE), and tried to set headers (Accept-Language, Content-Language) without any effect. How can I get the API to return the translated names through the interface?

Comment: Could we see an example of what you've tried?

Comment: I added headers in PHP:
header('Content-language: de');
header("Accept-Language: de-DE");

require_once('resources/facebook-php-sdk-master/src/facebook.php');

$facebook = new Facebook($config);

$since = strtotime("now");
$pagefeed = $facebook->api("/" . $pageid . "/events?since=$since&limit=20&locale=de&fields=id,name,location,start_time,ticket_uri,venue,description,cover");

and I tried to set &locale=de_DE